# Joining two into one SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

does anyone know to work this out?

i'm a dummie with SSIS, i have a derived column with WomenID, MenID, Date, and Status.
The thing is that i need to "join" WomenID and MenID into one (IDs) keeping the date and status, for example:

```
WomenID| MenID| Date      | Status
123    | 345  | 20160819  |  M
768    | 762  | 19870830  |  S
```

and need to turn it into

```
ID   |Date      |Status
123  |20160819  | M
768  |19870830  | S
345  |20160819  | M
762  |19870830  | S
```

I know that this is a trival question but can't see the light with this one.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a `UNION`:

```
SELECT WomenID AS ID, Date, Status FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT MenID, Date, Status FROM yourTable
```

If you want the exact ordering which you are showing us, we need to do more work.  A computed column is one way to go:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT WomenID AS ID, Date, Status, 0 AS position FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MenID, Date, Status, 1 FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, Date, Status
FROM cte
ORDER BY position, Status;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Yeah, i did think that but the records come from a flat file source

Comment: @Lorn Not sure I follow your comment.  If your data is in SQL Server, then my answer should work.  If the data _isn't_ in SQL Server, then you should load it in first.

Comment: Sure, the data comes from a FFS, should make this transformation before loading the records into SQL Server, thats the thing

Comment: @Lorn Complex data operations outside of SQL Server will probably be much harder than doing this in the database, at least this my feeling in this case.  You can always create a temp table in SQL Server, do your cleanup, then drop it later.

Comment: I think the same man, but they are asking to make it that way

Comment: Well I don't know how to do it.  Using only the options SQL Server has to read in data, you might have to read in the file twice, but you'd still ending up doing some work in the database, I think.

Comment: @Lorn (E)xtract s to typically move data into staging table(s) then (T)ranformation is done before (L)oading actual table(s). Tim's answer is the best approach

Comment: @Mazhar There are situations where data is so raunchy that it can't be loaded into a database, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
select womenid as Id, Date, status where status=‘F’
Union
Select menid as Id, Date, status where status=‘M’
```

Hope it helps